# How should I retrieve query vectors in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I am currently vectorizing entire documents using weighted sums, and I am unable to find any resources telling me how I should store the vocab dense vectors and how they should be retrieved.

So, essentially I have pairs:
`{'doc': dense_vector}` and `{'query': dense_vector}`

The former are stored in an Elasticsearch index, but I am not exactly sure how to store the word embeddings needed to compute the latter; I guess it will be in the same index. However, I am not sure what the best way of doing that is.

I am not sure how to retrieve the dense vector for the query. What are the best practices for doing that?

Comment: Why not use a separate index?

Comment: @ilvar No reason; I am basing my guess off of code I was handed over from a developer.

Comment: What queries are you going to run against this?

Comment: @ilvar I am not sure what you mean; I have a set of paragraphs I am using SIF to vectorize and these are what we have made searchable. The idea is to make the query into dense vectors as well using SIF, and run cosine similarity between that and the documents.

Comment: Why do you need to store queries?

Comment: @ilvar Well, I think I need to rephrase my question. I was thinking about the word embeddings, since the query embeddings need to be computed for each query..

Comment: So you're using [KNN](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/knn-search.html)?

Comment: @ilvar No, I am using cosine similarity between query embeddings and the document embeddings. For my particular use case it works quite well. I am just trying to make sure that when we move to actual production, it's done efficiently.

Comment: How you're computing cosine similarities?

Comment: @ilvar Why am I being interrogated...?
I am using the built-in function in Elasticsearch, as seen here:
https://www.elastic.co/blog/text-similarity-search-with-vectors-in-elasticsearch

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to sound rude, just wanted to understand the use case. Scripted approach might be quite slow for large datasets so you may consider benchmarking it against knn or a-knn.

Comment: @ilvar No worries.. Sure, thanks for the advice. I'll definitely try that. However, with KNN, I still have the original issue I asked for; That the word vectors will have to be stored, and retrieved from, somewhere when the user type their query.

Comment: But you don't know what user will enter right? So you receive the input, feed it to your text-to-vector ML model, get the query vector and then query ES to get docs closest to that vector. What am I missing?

Comment: @ilvar There is no text-to-vector ML model involved in this part of the workflow; That's not how Word2Vec, FastText and similar word embedding methods work. The language model is trained first to create {word,embeddding} pairs. These pairs are then stored somewhere and retrieved when the user types their query (I am ignoring misspellings and out-of-vocab queries for now).
As an example, the word 'okay' may have the pair ['word',(1,0.3,0.2...,1)]. So, when the user types 'okay', we need to retrieve the vector (1,0.3,0.2...,1) to do the rest.

Comment: @ilvar Having written that, I can rephrase my question; Is retrieving the embeddings from a Python function, as I think you suggest, really the most efficient way of doing this? The guy who worked on this before me seemed to think otherwise since he stored the embeddings in ES. I don't have time for benchmarking, so I was hoping there were some best practices I could learn here.

Comment: I see now, thanks. We were usually keeping those in memory or storing in a sqlite db, it's much more lean than an ES cluster. If you want to stick with ES I would probably use terms (or hashes of them) in document IDs to speed up lookups.

Comment: @ilvar Alright, thank you very much! That's the answer I was looking for.